# (PHP) after clicking the approve button next form should appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Iam working on this website where I have to output form data as a table from the database. I have also included approve and disapprove buttons beside the form. My problem is when ever i click the approve button the current table, the next table should appear.
Here is the code.

```
  echo '<table width = "30%" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing ="2" border = "2px">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong> ID</strong></td>
                    <td><strong> username</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> email</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> EC. no</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> GradePay</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> Division</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> ProjectCode</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> purpose of jourmey</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> TA</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> Address</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> Telephone</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> date of journey</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> return date</strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> From </strong> </td>
                    <td><strong> To</strong> </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['ecno'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['gradepay'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['division'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['code'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['journey'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['ta'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['tel'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['doj'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['dor'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['fc'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['tc'].'</td>
                    <td>  <input type= "submit" name="submit" value="approve" onclick ="myFunction()"></td>
                    <td>  <input type= "submit" name="submit1" value="decline" onclick ="myFunction1()"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>';    



    }
}
}
?>
```

[The image of this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U09Jx.png)

as shown in the image whenever i click the approve button , the next form should appear and this should move away from the page.
please help me with this problem

Comment: What did you try already? Can you show us a bit of your code? You can't expect us to just create the project you want, we're here to help you solve issues, not to do the work for you :)

Comment: yeah, sorry for that but i cant seem to figure out a code which once a button is clicked then next table should appear

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction(){
header("location:nextform.php");
}
```

I think this is what u want...